# Codeigniter 4 does not load CSS

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

CSS is not loaded in Codeigniter 4. My css file is located under /public/assets/css/app.css

I include it like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=base_url();?>/assets/css/app.css"/>
```

I have configured my .env file like this:

```
app.baseURL = 'http://localhost/[project_name]/'
```

.htaccess (default Codeigniter file)

```
DirectoryIndex /public/index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|assets|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./public/index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

The browser tries to load the file http://localhost/[project_name]/assets/css/app.css but it fails to load.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is your actual project name? It's definitely not [project_name] as that is just a placeholder that you need to change to suit your project name you are using.

Comment: Of course it's not actually [project_name]. I just put that as a placeholder here, in my config the real name is used.

Comment: I highly suspect there is a problem with your htaccess file. I wonder if the CSS request is being sent to Codeigniter when it shouldnt. Can you paste the contents of your htaccess file in the question?

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Are the files stored at the expected location?

Answer (score 0):

My english is poor but i'll try to help.
Do like this:

```
<link href="<?= site_url('/assets/css/app.css') ?>" rel="stylesheet">
```

After go in your /app/Config/Constants.php paste this code at the end of the file

```
$myappBaseUrl = ((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == "on") ? "https" : "http");
$myappBaseUrl .= "://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$myappBaseUrl .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
        
defined('BASESEURL') || define('BASESEURL',$myappBaseUrl);
```

Finally comment the line app.baseURL of your .env by adding # at the beginning of the line and define de variable $baseURL of app/Config/App.php like this:

```
public $baseURL = BASESEURL;
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with localhost (xammp);

1. Relocate your css to root project folder
2. Then use;
   `<?= base_url('../filename.css');?>`